# YUI CSS Minification issues

Tags: css, yui, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have 2 css files which are minified and combined into one file. But the CSS property on the same element is not combined.

file1.css // this comes from a common library

```
body { position: relative; margin: auto; }
```

file2.css //this is a project specific style

```
body { position: static }
```

min.css

```
body{position: relative; margin: auto}
body{position:static}
```

I want `position: static` to take precedence on `position: relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not a bug, YUI Compressor does not merge CSS selectors.

It's a choice, and it has a reason.**

Take this CSS as an example :

```
/* file1.css */
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.bar {
  color: blue;
}

/* file2.css */
.foo {
  color: yellow;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<p class="foo bar">Hello world!</p>
```

Here's what we've got:

### Without file combination

```
/* file1.css */
.foo{color:red;}.bar{color:blue;}

/* file2.css */
.foo{color:yellow;}
```

The color is **YELLOW**, because of the order of declarations.

### With file combination, without merging selectors

```
/* file1.css */
.foo{color:red;}.bar{color:blue;}.foo{color:yellow;}
```

The color is **YELLOW**, same reasons.

### With file combination and merging selectors

```
/* file1.css */
.foo{color:yellow;}.bar{color:blue;}
```

The color is **BLUE**, because our element has both selectors, and the yellow value has been moved during minification.

Comment: Does that mean, the last value of the css property selector gets applied and not the first (if we have same property specified at more than one place for the same element )?

Comment: They're all applied, but the last one override the first one. In your example, `static` already take precedence on `relative`, as it's declared later in your files.

Comment: But static does not take precedence in my case, its always relative, which is getting applied to the element

Comment: In this example, it's not static, for sure.

Comment: Correct ! It seems some one else was poking its nose in between, finally I had to declare the property at the end of the file and it worked. Thanks for the lucid explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of css files in your xml configuration file.

Comment: Which configuration file, do you mean the master page file of my web page ?

Comment: How you are minifying your css files, means where are you specifying the names of files to minify?

Comment: I add that as part of pre-build events. I changed the order of my css files, property order did get changed in the minified file, but still 'position: relative' gets applied.

Comment: position: static !important ; will work, but it's not a good solution. You can try with adding additional css class with css property as position: static.

Comment: @Arpit You misunderstood OP's question. The problem is not that `static` is applied instead of `relative` (this is normal, and the expected behavior), but that **both value are shown in the final minified CSS**. There should only have the last one, as they share the same selector.